# Persist last swinghigh and last swinglow in global variable

Tags: pine-script

Trying to persist in a global variable the last swinghigh and swinglow. As per my understanding the recipe would be:

- monitor candles open/close price in order to tell if it was a green or red candle.
- if it's red, store its low price in a variable, if its green, store high price in global var
- as new bars appear keep updating these values

So far I tried to identify and store the last red/green candles that way:

```
var last_green_candle = (close > open)
var last_red_candle = (open > close)
```

My idea was that I could store this "object" or it's high/low value but it appears that this expression only returns a boolean on the bar where the event happens but then I cannot access the value of high/low.

I'm skimming through the docs but I'm probably missing some important piece explaining how to access specific bar data and store it. Any input truly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `(close > open)` and `(open > close)` are comparisons and result in
`boolean`. `close` is either greater than `open` or not (`true`/`false`).

What you need to do is, use the ternary operator to update the value.

```
var last_green_candle = 0.0
var last_red_candle = 0.0

last_green_candle := (close > open) ? high : last_green_candle  // If it's a green candle, update the value with the new high, else, keep the old value
last_red_candle := (open > close) ? low : last_red_candle   // If it's a redcandle, update the value with the new low, else, keep the old value
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me and clarifying pine for the noob I am, it makes total sense now. Kind regards!

Comment: No worries, we are here to help and share the knowledge. `pine-script` is not a common language and might be difficult to grasp sometimes even for the experienced pine coders. Glad I was able to help. Happy coding and do not hesitate to come back whenever you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ta.valuewhen()` function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay = true)

last_green_candle = ta.valuewhen(close > open, high, 0)
last_red_candle =  ta.valuewhen(open > close, low, 0)

plot(last_green_candle, color = color.green)
plot(last_red_candle, color = color.red)
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this alternative option that i found more readable and idiomatic as it relies more on api objects and avoid ternary operator. Thanks for taking the time to share this input. Truly appreciated having an other option.